# Error 5 error C2039: 'update' : is not a member of 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'

Tags: c++, vector

this is probably simple, and I have tried to include the relevant stuff, but I have a header file called bullet.h

```
#include "basetype.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "draw.h"
#include "player.h"


class bullet : public basetype, draw 


{

public:

bullet();
~bullet();
void update();
void setposition(player &commando);

};

#endif
```

which has cpp

```
#include < iostream >
#include "bullet.h"
#include "AIE.h"


bullet::bullet()

{

sprite = CreateSprite( "./images/commando.png", 85, 85, true );

}


bullet::~bullet()

{

DestroySprite (sprite);

}


void bullet::update()

{


    MoveSprite ( sprite, position.fposX, position.fposY );
    drawsprite();

    position.fposY +=4.f;


}
```

in basetype.h I include < vector > and < iterator >

so in my main I have this issue

```
std::vector<bullet*> oBullets;
std::vector<bullet*> :: iterator iterator;


if (IsKeyDown (' '))

{

        oBullets.push_back(new bullet());

}

for (iterator = oBullets.begin(); iterator != oBullets.end(); iterator++)

{

            *iterator.update();

}
```

and it keeps talling me update is not a member of iterator, but to my knowledge ive set iterator as a bullet, and bullet.update() should exist, so stumped, feel like an idiot

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the vector are pointers, so you need two de-references: one for the iterator, one for the pointer:

```
(*iterator)->update();
```